# How to consider 4 vars in an if-else statement

Tags: javascript

I have a code with 4 vars named Alex John Billy and Bob. I created an if-else statement and for now i only want the if statement to execute if ANY of the var's `this.age` value is found under 14 , and else statement if all vars are over 14

but right now only the else statement executes and i am assuming its because 2/4 vars have `this.age` value over 14. My question is how exactly can i consider all vars

```
function person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var Alex = new person("Alex", 15);
var John = new person("John", 16);
var Billy = new person("Billy", 13);
var Bob = new person("Bob", 11);

if(this.age < 14){
    document.write("oops!");
}
else{
    document.write("yay!");
}
```

Comment: create an array where you will add all your Persons in it. Then iterate into this array to verify the age. Also.. Don't use "this".

Comment: You can iterate through the above-mentioned array with `Array.prototype.some()`, using a function to check each `person.age` value. The `.some()` method returns `true` or `false`, and that's what should drive your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push your `person` objects into another object, I've called it `persons`. Then you can loop through all the entries with a [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of all the keys, or person objects in this case.

```js
function person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

const persons = {};

persons.Alex = new person("Alex", 15);
persons.John = new person("John", 16);
persons.Billy = new person("Billy", 13);
persons.Bob = new person("Bob", 11);

for (let pers of Object.keys(persons)) {
  if (persons[pers].age < 14) {
    console.log(persons[pers].name+": oops!");
  } else {
    console.log(persons[pers].name+": yay!");
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As it transpires you only want one outcome for all the objects, this will change our code a little.

Now it's best to [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) all the objects to an array, again, called `persons` then you can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check each `object` against a function. If all the values pass you will get a `TRUE` but if one or more fail you will get a `FALSE`

```js
function person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

const persons = [];

persons.push(new person("Alex", 15));
persons.push(new person("John", 16));
persons.push(new person("Billy", 13));
persons.push(new person("Bob", 11));

if (persons.every(p => { p.age > 14 })) {
  console.log('Yay!')
} else {
  console.log('oops!')
}
```

**Keeping the object:**

If you want to keep the object for ease of use later we can make an array of all the ages using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

const persons = {};

persons.Alex = new person("Alex", 15);
persons.John = new person("John", 16);
persons.Billy = new person("Billy", 13);
persons.Bob = new person("Bob", 11);

if (!Object.keys(persons).map(k => {
    return persons[k].age
  }).some(e => e < 14)) {
  console.log('Yay!');
} else {
  console.log('oops!');
}
```

Comment: Im looking for a result of only yay! or oops! if all vars fit the criteria, not individual outcomes

Answer (score 2):

You could add your objects to an array and then check if at least one of the contained objects has an age lower than 14 using [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

persons = [];

persons.push(new person("Alex", 15));
persons.push(new person("John", 16));
persons.push(new person("Billy", 13));
persons.push(new person("Bob", 11));

if(persons.some(p => p.age < 14)){
    document.write("oops!");
}
else{
    document.write("yay!");
}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer, especially if there's a lot of data to get through.

Answer (score 0):

Create array for the 4person and use .map() to check them all like this example

```js
function person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
var Alex = new person("Alex", 15);
var John = new person("John", 16);
var Billy = new person("Billy", 13);
var Bob = new person("Bob", 11);
var persons = [Alex, John, Billy, Bob];
persons.map(prrson => {
  if (prrson.age < 14) {
    console.log("oops!");
  } else {
    console.log("yay!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple possibilities so you want to create an array after we will check.

```js
function person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var Alex = new person("Alex", 15);
var John = new person("John", 16);
var Billy = new person("Billy", 13);
var Bob = new person("Bob", 11);

var ages = [Alex.age, John.age, Billy.age, Bob.age];


for (i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
  if (ages[i] < 14) {
    document.write("oops!");
  } else {
    document.write("yay!");
  }
}
```